# C# Dependency injection duplicating

Tags: c#

I'm making an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web application. In my application I use the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ICalendarService _calendarService;

    public MyClass(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, ICalendarService calendarService)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _calendarService = calendarService;
    }

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        // here I need to use _dbContext and _calendarService
    }
```

But when I use this class I need to do the following:

```
public class MySecondClass
{
     private ImportIntoCalendar ImportHintSchedule;
     public MySecondClass()
     {
         MyClass= new MyClass(_dbContext, _calendarService);
     }

     // Do something with variable ImportHintSchedule
     ImportHintschedule.Function()
}
```

Everytime I need to add the dbcontext and the calendarservice into the parameters. So both need to be available in the other class. This feels like I'm doing something stupid, like I'm duplicating the same step. Does anybody know a better way to do this. Or is this just fine?

Edit: 
I have this line in my startup.cs

```
 services.AddScoped<ICalendarService, CalendarService>();
```

Comment: You got the dependency injection pattern right, but you need something to handle instantiating your concrete classes, this is what an IoC container solves.  .NET Core [has one built in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1).  Check the `ConfigureServices()` method in your Startup.cs file.  There is where you register the mappings `IInterface -> ImplementationClass`

Comment: @maccettura I have actually done that. But I still don't know how to use it. Because when I make an object it needs it in the parameter

Comment: @Littleprogrammingwizard One "trick" to DI is to avoid creating new objects. In other words, avoid invoking constructors. In the code I write, the only time I call constructors is to create model (or POCO) classes that just contain data, no logic. [This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) is an absolute must watch if you're learning DI in C#.

Comment: @mason Thanks for the video, I will definitely watch that. How can I avoid invoking the MyClass constructor in my example? In the second code block

Comment: @Littleprogrammingwizard yeah as mason said, the whole point of dependency injection is that you stop instantiating objects by hand.  For your second code block just change your constructor so that it takes `public MySecondClass(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, ICalendarService calendarService)`

Comment: Actually, I would change `MySecondClass` to accept an `IMyClass` (which should be a new interface that MyClass implements) as part of its constructor. Classes should never depend directly on concrete implement of other logic-containing classes (services).

Answer (score 0):

In your ConfigureServices you can add the IOC scopes.

For example, something like this. I don't know all of your code so the is just an example.

```
services.AddScoped<ICalendarService, CalendarService>();
services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

You can also add singletons if that meets your needs as well.
Here is an example singleton call I use in my application

```
services.AddSingleton<IRepository<BaseItem>>(x => new Repository<BaseItem>(Configuration["MongoConnection:DefaultConnection"]));
```

Comment: I have that line in my startup. See edit. But I still need to add the injection. Or am I doing something wrong. Can you provide an example of how to use it in a class?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an `Interface` of your class, something like:

```
public interface IMyClass {
    void MyFunction();
}
```

Then, implement that in your class:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ICalendarService _calendarService;

    public MyClass(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, ICalendarService calendarService)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _calendarService = calendarService;
    }

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        // here I need to use _dbContext and _calendarService
    }
 }
```

And the add that to injector:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // existing code
    services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
}
```

and finally use `IMyClass` in `Controller` constructor.

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
   private IMyInterface _myClass;
   public MyController(IMyInterface myclass) {
      _myClass = myClass;
   }

   public IActionResult MyAction() {
      _myClass.MyFunction();
      return View();
   }
}
```